# Wildcard in filename keeps failing in my shell script

Tags: shell

**Scenario:** I'm logging into a docker container to restore a mongodb dump. There is only one dump file in the volume.

If I use a wild card in the file name I get the errors below but if I give the full file name it works. I've spent a few hours searching forums but can't find an answer. What is missing from my script?

```
root@141782f66c37:/data/backup# ./mongoretore.sh
./mongoretore.sh: line 2: dump_06-11-2020_20-32-15.dump: command not found
./mongoretore.sh: line 2: `*.dump`: ambiguous redirect
```

**WORKING**

```
#!/bin/bash
mongorestore --drop --archive < dump_06-11-2020_20-32-15.dump
```

**NOT WORKING**

```
#!/bin/bash
mongorestore --drop --archive < `*.dump`
```

Comment: `\`...\`` is the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) syntax. It will try to execute the content as a command and "return" the output. `dump_06-11-2020_20-32-15.dump` is not a command. What's the reason you are using backticks here?

Comment: tbh I was reading around in circles and by putting backticks I could see it was showing me the correct filename. I just want to use filecard like I would in JS, Java or multitudes of other languages so it's obvious I don't know what's happening here. If I don't add backticks I get the error `./mongoretore.sh: line 2: *.dump: ambiguous redirect`

Comment: I don't know why you are getting this error specifically, but you could do `cat *.dump | mongorestore ...` instead. Of course that might not work as you expect if there are multiple `.dump` files.

Comment: How do you expect `< *.dump` to work with multiple files existing? It's not clear what you _want_ to happen in that case; if we don't know what you want, we can't suggest a way to get there. (Keep in mind that each file descriptor can point to only one place; that place can be a stdout of a program like `cat` that reads from multiple inputs one-after-the-other, but there's still just one of them).

Comment: Anyhow, `< *.dump` _is indeed_ an ambiguous redirection, so the error message is correct; it isn't guaranteed to refer to _only a single file_.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy there is only ever one dump file in the volume folder. My pipeline places the latest DB dump in that folder and so I just needed a script to use whatever dump file it found. That way I don't have to keep editing the script or manually type the command and my docker build can run the script.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy your second comment points out it is ambiguous but only if there are multiple files. I did not realise the command would preempt that scenario.

Comment: @FelixKling `cat *.dump | mongorestore ...` that worked thank you.

Comment: BTW, consider making it `cat /dev/null *.dump | ...` so it doesn't hang waiting for content on stdin if there somehow aren't _any_ `.dump` files (and if you have the `nullglob` option set).

Comment: (Yes, you might _expect_ there to be only exactly one file, but it's never a good idea to write code without thinking about what the failure modes are when the expectations it was written with were wrong; one of the worst commercial data-loss scenarios I've personally witnessed was caused by just such an error -- someone assuming that a naming convention would always be correctly followed, in that case).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Wholeheartedly agree and I would never take this approach in work. This is my own toy project that has sort of grown over the last 5 years and I'm just trying to automate as much as I can now. Esp. after a NAS HD fail last week 
I have terrible OCD with tech and I can never sleep until I understand why it didn't work but all is good now 